# STM32F767ZI Cycle Counter for time measurement

Tags: c, time, stm32

I have a STM32F767ZI Nucleo board and it runs with 216MHz (SYSCLK and HCLK).

[image]

My code was generated with STM32CubeMX. I want to use the cycle counter to get the needed cycles for a certain function, my code looks like this:

```
DWT->CYCCNT = 0;

uint32_t counter1 = DWT->CYCCNT; 
//test_function();
uint32_t counter2 = DWT->CYCCNT;

uint32_t cycles= counter2 - counter1;
```

So am I right, if I want to calculate the elapsed time of my `test_function()`, my formular looks something like that:

`time_in_seconds = cycles/216*10^6`

And my `test_function` takes more time, if I'm reducing the MHz of my board?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The formula looks wrong. Integer division, 10^6 isn't 1000000 and priorities. It might be counted as `(cycles/216)*(10^6)` or  `((cycles/216)*10)^6` where `^` is bitwise XOR operation not power.

Comment: `time_in_seconds = cycles/216*10^6` -> `time_in_seconds = cycles/216e6` time_in_seconds must be double or float